# Bug in Line Breaks?

Tags: line-breaking

A certain line I have written seems to never want to break on the pair of words "on groups", unless I forcibly add `\linebreak`. I demonstrate this in the following picture, which uses `~` to force certain words together; code below. I don't know why it won't break between "on" and "groups".

I don't have a solution/reason for this myself. I can easily fix it by just adding `\linebreak` if I end up keeping this sentence in this position. I'm just posting it here for those who are interested and/or work on TeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={210mm,297mm},
    left    = 35mm,
    right   = 35mm,
    top     = 35mm,
    bottom  = 35mm,
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

%\lipsum[1]

Teyssier's original approximation lemma is written for conjugacy-invariant RWs on groups. We ttttttttttttt it to RWs on homogeneous spaces corresponding to Gelfand pairs...

Teyssier's original approximation lemma is written for conjugacy-invariant RWs on groups.~We ttttttttttttt it to RWs on homogeneous spaces corresponding to Gelfand pairs...

Teyssier's original approximation lemma is written for conjugacy-invariant RWs on groups.~We~ttttttttttttt it to RWs on homogeneous spaces corresponding to Gelfand pairs...

Teyssier's original approximation lemma is written for conjugacy-invariant RWs on groups.~We~tttttttttttttttttttttttt it to RWs on homogeneous spaces corresponding to Gelfand pairs...

Teyssier's original approximation lemma is written for conjugacy-invariant RWs on\linebreak groups. We ttttttttttttt it to RWs on homogeneous spaces corresponding to Gelfand pairs...

%\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

David Carlisle suggests below that TeX does not allow word-spacing as large as in the final line without manual input. I haven't verified this personally, but I presume he is correct. I guess this is more a *design flaw* than a *bug*.
Surely no-one prefers an overfull box so large that the text goes beyond the margin and doesn't actually get printed versus a slightly larger inter-word space!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no bug here, breaking after `on` would require stretching the inter-word spaces more than is allowed by default. You could use `\sloppy` to allow white space to stretch more, then it does break there.

Comment: So it's better to extend *forever* (it appears)? One can argue about whether a 4.3pt overflow is better than moving "groups" to the next line, but clearly the penultimate one is not better by anyone's measure! I must confess, I am skeptical of your claim that the stretch would be more than allowed, too... I am close to certain that I have had some which are stretched *significantly* more in the past—like, maybe 1.5x as much. Still, you are extremely knowledgeable, so maybe I'm mistaken! Either way, it's either a bug or a design flaw =P

Comment: @SamOT I do not see why you think it is a design flaw, it seems expected behaviour to me. There are always some paragraphs that give over or underfull box warnings and need some hand adjusment. As for the amount of sretch being the issue, you don't need to believe me, try it with `\sloppy` (I did check in advance that that worked in his case). TeX will always prefer to have an ovrfull box (with a warning) rather than over-stretch the space, so if you never want overfull boxes you should allow the space to stretch more.

Comment: I'm not suggesting one should *never* want certain things. Just, clearly, the penultimate version is a lot worse than the final version! It's picking an option that (surely) most people would say is worse—arguable, even *objectively* worse. That's what I meant by "design flaw". I guess one could summarise the issue as "having a (pretty small) maximum stretch, but no maximum overfull—including going so far into the margin that it's no longer printed on the page". Ideally, I just rephrase/structure my sentence/paragraph. This way, by designing my writing better, I avoid both pitfalls! :)

Comment: @SamOT I think I once saw someone argue that if one has to choose between typesetting overfull and underfull boxes, overfull boxes are the better choice because they are easier to spot. Both cases need user intervention, but overfull boxes show more clearly that something is wrong. If you don't want to go all the way to `\sloppy`, setting `\emergencystretch` to a high value should make underfull boxes more likely.

Comment: @SamOT actually it is rather the other way, underful boxes are allowed at varying degrees of badness but any overfull box is maximally bad.  One consequnce of that is that a box that is 1 metre over full is no worse than a box that is 1pt overfull. This does mean (and Knuth even documents it in the texbook) that the one really bad overfull line gets preferred over lots of fairly bad lines, That may not mach your intuition but it's aa rational outcome of the least cost algorithm used to find line breaks.

Comment: I get that. I personally make sure that I *never* had overfull boxes. I think they are pretty close to unacceptable. But the error is pretty hidden away—both for underfull and overfull. I would agree with your reasoning that iti should go for overfull rather than underfull if there were always to be none. But the error just isn't made very clear. Sometimes it's 1pt over and I just don't notice. Let's be honest, very few people check the error log! Maybe *something like* a different exit code would help? Maybe a bit extreme, but something which is actually visible without checking logs...

Comment: This is coming from deep in tex's loop so nothing latex can change, and pdftex won't change it either. Personally I look at logs more than I look at the pdf output, but I realise I'm not a typical user @SamOT

Comment: Ah, I don't understand the difference between tex/latex well. And yes, there are few people worldwide who have quite your level of la/tex understanding and skill!!